# Deep underneath us where two tectonic plates are pushing past each other

Tags: commas

Are the following versions both okay? If so, what is the function of the first comma in (b)?

> a. Deep underneath us where two tectonic plates are pushing past each other, magma heats groundwater.

> b. Deep underneath us, where two tectonic plates are pushing past each other, magma heats groundwater.

Comment: Some commas are optional. There's usually more to your questions than what's on the surface. Is there anything more than that?

Comment: I am thinking about the restrictive vs. non-restrictive distinction in relative clauses. I'm wondering if the distinction applies to this curious case, where the relative clause modifies the prepositional phrase "deep underneath us."

Comment: Ah, no, in this case, I read it as just a succession of adverbial phrases describing a place. One does not define the other in either version. It's probably better with a comma, but not incorrect without it.

Comment: Is the "where" relative clause restrictive or non-restrictive?

Comment: I don't think it's a relative clause at all. What noun does it modify? I think it's an adverbial of place. The sentence could be, "*Deep beneath us, magma heats groundwater where two tectonic plates are pushing past each other.*"

Comment: Some relatives modify adverbials. One notable example is in "Life on the open waters meant that finally he'd be living somewhere **he could escape the long shadow the accident had cast over his life**.  Here, "somewhere" is modified by the boldfaced clause.

Comment: Some people may think that 'beneath' is more formal than 'underneath'.

Comment: @Apollyon "Somewhere" is a pronoun, so it can be modified by a relative clause. In your example in the question, there's no noun to modify.

Comment: "Somewhere" is an adverb there. It is modifying the verb "living."